# css border fades out

Tags: css, browser

I have a border created by the css below.  `.left` is a div and and `.left-menu` is an ASP.NET menu control nested inside `.left`.  Something I don't understand happens when the border is rendered in IE, FF and Chrome.  The border appears initially and then slowly fades away and disappears completely.  There is no javascript running.  It doesn't appear to be an animation and is NOT a gradient.  The border appears initially and then immediately begins to fade into the white background and then completely disappears.  The whole thing takes about 2-3 seconds.  If I change the color to something like #ff0000, the border remains and does NOT fade away.

```
.left
{    
    min-height: 400px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 50px;
    border-right: 2px solid #f1f1f2;
    float: left;
}

.left-menu, .left-menu ul
{
    width: 100% !important;
}

.left-menu ul li a
{    
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px; 
    padding-right: 50px;    
}
```

Comment: Fades and disappears as in animates away, or it looks like a gradient of some sort? If it's the former, we need to see your jQuery or other JS code. If it's the latter, a screenshot or link to the site/example would be very helpful.

Comment: Sounds like you've got some javascript running wild on your div or on global borders. Can we see what's inside your head tag?

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered the problem is, in fact, rogue javascript generated by the ASP.NET menu control.  The DisappearAfter property is being manipulated and actually fades out the border immediately after rendering.  Oddly enough, this functionality is buggy, since an unrelated border on the div above the menu is removed as well.  Also, changing the border color from the menu mouseover color to another color persists the border.